# Google Docs Embed on PHP Site

Tags: php, google-docs-api

I've been reading through Google Docs API and having some trouble. I want to do the following:

1. Embed a Google Doc in my web application
2. Anyone who can access that page in the web app can edit the Google Doc, without having to sign in to their Google account
3. (If Possible) Show who made which changes using their identities in my web app, not their Google account.

Comment: Do you have anything to show for it at all? Any attempts? Mind posting code you are having issues with?

Comment: I've looked at the API and done my due diligence. I'm not asking for full code, I'm just asking for some guidance to whether this is possible and what it would entail. I'd be happy to google the details of implementation myself.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are a few ways you can embed. A quick Google search will yield several answers.
2. As far as I know, it's not possible to edit without signing into an account.
3. As this is related to (2), I don't think this is possible as all.